# Python : How to convert a CSV file stored in Byte stream to a List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, bytestream

I am trying to get a csv file from Azure Data Lake Gen2, and then perform some operations on each row. However, the requirement is, not to download the file to a physical location. And hence, I am using `file_client.download_File().readAll()` to get the file in a Byte Stream.

However, I am unable to split the file rows/columns and get them into a list.

```
 x = file_client.download_file()
 bystream = x.readall()
```

WHAT TO DO WITH THIS bystream ?

I am however able to do this with downloaded file using `WITH OPEN () AS CSV` and then using this CSV stream in `csv.reader()`

Can someone please help with handling this bytestream?

Comment: readall() method just download the entire file. Then use pandas.read_csv() isn't this work?

Comment: Thank you Isuru, pandas.read_csv() was a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

A late update that I was able to resolve this issue by converting the downloaded stream to Text I/O. (didnt need to convert it to List, as Pandas Dataframe was better option)

Here is the code snippet that worked :

```
 stream = io.StringIO(file_client.download_file().readall().decode("utf-8"))
 dataframe1 = pd.read_csv(stream, sep= "|")
```

Here, file_client is connection to an Azure Data Lake where the csv file is stored.
The code downloads the file as a stream in-memory, and loads it to a dataframe. (No need to write it to a local file location)